# How to get syndaemon to work every time I restart the computer or switch accounts?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

What is the surefire way to disable the touchpad while typing?

I run syndaemon and it works for a bit.  But it's notoriously unreliable.  Every time my wife uses the computer it's stopped again.  We have different accounts.  I get the problem too but I don't seem to knock the touchpad like she does.

I suspect it's an issue with how it starts.  I've tried starting it from all sorts of places.  Why cant Ubuntu get this right?  It should be started by default on laptops.

Hints please.  My wife is bugging me every time she goes to use to the computer and she's getting quite grumpy about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to config the auto generated .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart

Something like:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 10&&/usr/bin/syndaemon -i 0.5 -d -K"
```